# Javascript https calls http

Tags: node.js, express, http, cors

In my webpage on `https://mywebsite.org` with a script calling `http://other-domain.com`, it works until mywebsite is in `http`, but when mywebsite is in `https` the http call is blocked!

The server side of `http://other-domain.com` was build in nodeJS and Express. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "_when mywebsite is in https the http call is blocked_"? Do you get a CORS error in your browser's Console tab? If so, add the error message to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to set up a CORS policy at the server on `other-domain.com`.
Here's the middleware that you have to use https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

`cors` has options so you can restrict the access to a specific domain. In your case this will be probably mywebsite.org.

Comment: cors is setted 

```app
 .use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
   if( !origin || origin === undefined || typeof origin === "undefined" ) callback(null, true);
   else {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
     callback(null, true)
    } else {
     callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
   }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
 }))```

but request from https is always blocked!

Comment: Do you have your domain in the `whitelist` array?

Comment: of course @Krasimir

Comment: The most common problem based on your description is CORS issues. If it is not that then could be some sort of stack problem. Without giving more information we can't help you. Do you use AWS or GCP? Do you have load balancer? Who is taking the request on the first place. It will help also to post the message from the console (if any).